# any major performance improvements in SubSonic 3.0.0.4 vs 2.1?

Tags: performance, subsonic, upgrade

Is it worth upgrading to the latest stable version of SubSonic over 2.1?  We are running into some performance and scalability issues that are quickly becoming unacceptable and I haven't really been able to find anything definitive that points to anything that could really help.

I'm going to see if I can harness out some testing models but thought I'd ask.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help, but I have found a major factor in write performance depends on the presence of default values in tables.  Subsonic 2.1 performs a SELECT against the database for each value when creating a new record, and these can really slow things down.  It wouldn't be too hard to write a patch to cache these if constant (clearly you don't want to cache 'SELECT GetDate()', but 'SELECT 1' isn't going to yield too many surprises).
Not sure what 3.x does here; I haven't gone there yet.

This may be of no use if write performance is not the issue, but in that case more info would be good.

Comment: I was curious about the performance gains of the BatchQuery method available to 3.0. Alot of the processes that we use generate hundreds if not thousands of to/from trips to the db, but I might try the default value options.